# Process spawned by Windows service runs 3 to 4 times more slowly than spawned by GUI

Tags: c++, windows, service, macros

I have written a service application in Borland C++. It works fine. In the ServiceStart(TService *Sender,bool &Started) routine, I call mjwinrun to launch a process which picks up and processes macros. This process has no UI and any errors are logged to a file. It continues to run, until the server is restarted, shut down, or the process is terminated using Task Manager. Here is mjwinrun :-

```
int mjwinrun(AnsiString cmd)
{
  STARTUPINFO mjstupinf; PROCESS_INFORMATION mjprcinf;
  memset(&mjstupinf,0,sizeof(STARTUPINFO)); mjstupinf.cb=sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
  if (!CreateProcess(NULL,cmd.c_str(),NULL,NULL,TRUE,0,NULL,GetCurrentDir().c_str(),&mjstupinf,&mjprcinf))
  {
    LogMessage("Could not launch "+cmd); return -1;
  }
  CloseHandle(mjprcinf.hThread); CloseHandle(mjprcinf.hProcess);
  return mjprcinf.dwProcessId;
}
```

cmd is the command line for launching the macro queue processor. I used a macro that is CPU/Memory intensive and got it to write its timings to a file. Here is what I found :-

1) If the macro processor is launched from the command line within a logged on session, no matter what Windows core it is running under, the macro is completed in 6 seconds.

2) If the macro processor is launched from a service starting up on Vista core or earlier (using mjwinrun above), the macro is completed in 6 seconds.

3) If the macro processor is launched from a service starting up on Windows 7 core or later (using mjwinrun above), the macro is completed in more than 18 seconds.

I have tried all the different flags for CreateProcess and none of them make a difference. I have tried all different accounts for the service and that makes no difference. I tried setting all of the various priorities for tasks, I/O and Page, but they all make no difference. It's as if the service's spawned processes are somehow throttled, not in I/O terms, but in CPU/memory usage terms. Any ideas what changed in Windows 7 onwards?

Comment: Unlikely to be CPU unless the system is running flat out already.  What is the macro actually doing?

Comment: The CPU maxes out a core as it performs the macro. It reads in some data from a database and does some heavy processing to put it into human-readable form into a plain text output file (CSV format). You can see it read bytes using task manager, and it reads them in blocks of 3 or 4KBytes, with the occasional burst to 400-500KBytes at a time every 5 seconds. On the faster platform, these bursts occur every second.

Comment: If it maxes out a single core in either scenario then clearly the process isn't being CPU throttled.  Perhaps Windows 7 is power saving more aggressively?  The CPU core running at low frequency is the only reasonable explanation I can think of for 100%-for-eighteen-seconds in one scenario giving you the same amount of actual computation as 100%-for-six-seconds in the other scenario.

Comment: Perhaps it is the power scheme used. A service has no logged-in user profile to look up which power profile to use, hence, it may be using the default "Balanced" one, or a more conservative one. Does anyone know anything more about the power scheme a Windows service selects to use?

Comment: AFAIK, the currently active power scheme affects the entire computer, not individual processes.

Comment: More research on this problem has yielded the fact that it is the service (and any child processes it launches) that is slow. I coded the service to run the same code the macro was running on the same data and then got that same code to run when one of my GUI apps started. The time difference is C:\KFWS\scripts\viewdbfwinq.exe -q1
587 records reported in 4.425 seconds.
C:\KFWS\scripts\UsersService.exe
587 records reported in 18.092 seconds.

Comment: What happens if you run `psexec -s \\127.0.0.1 viewdbfwingq.exe -q1` ?  (The psexec tool can be downloaded from the MS web site.)

Comment: Useful looking suite of apps there. In the meantime, I solved my issue - see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I isolated code to reproduce this, and it eventually boiled down to calls to the database engine to lookup a field definition (TTable methods FindField and FieldByName). These took much longer on a table with a lot of fields when run on a service app instead of a GUI app. I devised my own method to store mappings from field names to field definitions, since I always opened my databases with a central routine. I used an array of strings indexed by the Tag property on each table (common to all BCB objects), where each string was composed of ;fieldname;fieldnumber; pairs, and then did a .Pos of the field name to get the field number. fieldnumber is zero-padded to a width of 4. This only uses a few hundred KB of RAM for the entire app and all of its databases. Once in place, the service app runs at the same speed as the GUI app. The only thing I can think of that may explain this, is that service apps have a fixed heap (I think I read 48MBytes somewhere by default) for themselves and any process they spawn. With lots of fields, the memory overflowed and had to thrash to VM on the disk. The GUI app had no such limit and was able to do the lookup entirely in real memory. However, I maybe completely wrong. One thing I have learnt is that FieldByName and FindField are expensive TTable functions to call, and I have now supplanted them all with my own mechanism which seems to work much better and much faster. Here is my lookup routine :-

```
AnsiString fldsbytag[MXSPRTBLS+100];

TField *fldfromtag(TAdsTable *tbl,AnsiString fld)
{
  int fi=fldsbytag[tbl->Tag].Pos(";"+fld.UpperCase()+";"),gi;
  if (fi==0) return tbl->FindField(fld);
  gi=StrToIntDef(fldsbytag[tbl->Tag].SubString(fi+fld.Length()+2,4),-1);
  if (gi<0 || gi>=tbl->Fields->Count) return tbl->FindField(fld);
  return tbl->Fields->Fields[gi];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be very difficult to give an authoritative answer to this question without a lot more details.

However a factor to consider is the Windows foreground priority boost described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684828(v=vs.85).aspx).

You may want to read Russinovich's book chapter on processes/threads, in particular the stuff on scheduling. You can find PDFs of the book online (there are two that together make up the whole book). I believe the latest (or next to latest) edition covers changes in Win 7.

Comment: I already tried the priority boost flag and it made no difference. What surprises me is that nobody has researched this before, considering there are loads of complaints on the net about how going from XP to Win7, or Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008 R2 has slowed down their operations. I reckon it could be something to do with this. Perhaps Microsoft foresaw a raft of new services being added to their latest OS offerings, and throttled service performance so as not to make the GUI apps appear sluggish.

Comment: Someone has researched this in depth. Mark Russinovich in the book I mentioned. BTW, I wasn't talking about a flag to CreateProcess, rather I was talking about a behavior of the scheduler.